# Very simple condition in macros

Tags: macros, conditionals

I try to define a macro in LaTeX. This macro should give a different output when I use condition `true` and `false`.

This does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newif\ifABC
\ifABC
\newcommand{\abcdef}[1]{{Letters} #1}%
\else
\newcommand\abcdef[1]{}
\fi

\begin{document}
\ABCtrue
\abcdef{ABC}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}%
```

How I should define conditional macro?

Comment: I am very beginner in terms of macros in TeX. Thank you, @Ian, @egreg!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check the conditional when the macro is executed, not when it is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newif\ifABC
\newcommand{\abcdef}[1]{\ifABC{Letters} #1\fi}
\begin{document}
\ABCtrue
\abcdef{ABC}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}%
```